# How can I detect a touch up inside in my custom view?

Tags: iphone

I've created a subclass of UIScrollView to implement a one of my custom controls, at this point everything is working great.

However what I'd like to be able to call a methods whenever a Touch Up Inside event is detected (just like interface builder) does anybody know how I could do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `UIScrollView` does not inherit from `UIControl`, this is not possible. You can, however, relay the scroll view's touch events by implementing the `UIResponder` methods in your custom `UIScrollView` class:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{   
    if (!self.dragging)
    {
        [self.nextResponder touchesEnded: touches withEvent:event]; 
    }       

    [super touchesEnded: touches withEvent: event];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (!self.dragging)
    {
        [self.nextResponder touchesBegan: touches withEvent:event]; 
    }       

    [super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];
}
```

Comment: I'll give that a try. Btw what is nextResponder and what does it do?

Comment: `nextResponder` returns the view's view controller to relay instructions, but in your case, it returns the parent view since the scroll view is not in a view controller stack. More here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIResponder

Comment: Is there a way to intercept these without subclassing `UIScrollView`?

Comment: UIScrollView and UIResponder are both class in Swift while Swift only allow one super class. How would I get the touch event using Swift?